# Linking an Arduino program in Java

Tags: java, arduino, netbeans-7

I have written a program in Arduino to detect intrusion using an ultrasonic sensor. And when it detects intrusion, a camera must be triggered. I have written the triggering program in Java in the [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) IDE. But I don't know how to link the Arduino program with Java. I browsed many sites and came across the blog post *[Arduino and Java](http://silveiraneto.net/2009/03/01/arduino-and-java)*, but I got an error while running the program.

The error is at the line `Preference.init()` How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: Are you trying to write a program in Java and have it run on Arduino? Or you want the Java program to talk to the Arduino (which will be running a program written in C)?  The confusion comes from the word "link": is it compile-type `link` or interface-type `link`?

Comment: Have you looked at Processing? http://processing.org . It creates programs that run on your desktop, which can interface with Arduinos and Webcams.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java application running on some computer or board can communicate with your Arduino application via serial communication link. This can be RS232 for shorter distances (up to 30m if 9600bps is used), or RS485 for up to 1200m. You need touse some known protocol, or make your own. This link can also be wireless if needed. More complex would be to put bluetooth on both sides, if that is more convinient for some reason. Alternatively, if you have an ethernet shield for Arduino you can implement UDP or TCP messaging to notify Java application about Arduino events. Instead of sending an event only when it happens, you can also think about periodical polling from Java application.